# Call a macro from ThisOutlookSession

Tags: vba, outlook, com-automation

I have a problem with my macros on outlook.

I am currently trying via a batch to call outlook and pass it as a parameter the name of a macro that I get via an environment variable I've set in my batch. However I do get the name of my macro, but the process stops at the time of the Call function. Could someone tell me the right way to proceed?

VBA ThisOutlookSession

```vb
Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim strMacroName As String
    strMacroName = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Environment("process").Item("MacroName")
    'MsgBox strMacroName
    'MsgBox VarType(strMacroName)
    If strMacroName <> "" Then Call strMacroName
    End Sub
```

VBA Modules

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub macro1()
MsgBox "macro1"
End Sub
Sub macro2()
MsgBox "macro2"
End Sub
```

Batch

```
Set WorkingPath=C:\Temp\Outlook
Set MacroName=%1
start OUTLOOK.EXE
Set MacroName=
Set WorkingPath=
```

the result

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several aspects here... The first point is possible security issues when dealing with the Outlook. You can read more about that in the [Security Behavior of the Outlook Object Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/security/security-behavior-of-the-outlook-object-model) article.

Another point is that you can call VBA macros declared in the `ThisOutlookSession` module in the following way (for example, from any other Office application):

```
Sub test()
  Dim OutApp As Object
  Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
  OutApp.Session.Logon
  OutApp.HelloWorld
End Sub
```

Where the `HelloWorld` sub is declared in the `ThisOutlookSession` module in following way:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub HelloWorld()
  MsgBox "Hello world !!"
End Sub
```

Note, you may call any module from the `ThisOutlookSession` module. There is no need to get access to other modules directly.

Comment: I was trying your code from excel and I got Object doesn't support this property or method (Error 438) in OutApp.HelloWorld. Any hint to fix this?